# глагол "сделать" и предлоги "в" или "для"

Tags: глаголы, управление

Хотелось уточнить, как правильно использовать глагол "сделать" в следующем контексте:
*Он много сделал в разработке новых материалов.*
или
*Он много сделал для разработки новых материалов.*
Если можно, поясните, пожалуйста, как обосновать правильное использование (какие здесь участвуют правила).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл несколько различается.

> Он много сделал **в** разработке [стилистически лучше: *в области*
>   *разработки*] новых материалов.

Речь выше может идти о **достижениях** в указанной *области*, напр., на протяжении профессиональной карьеры.

> Он много сделал **для** разработки новых материалов.

Здесь: он внёс свой вклад в какое-то общее дело (прилагал **усилия**, участвовал).

Comment: Предположим, что меценат Вася спонсирует проект по разработке новых материалов, где Вова и Петя трудятся не покладая рук и в результате разрабатывают супертоний. 
Все трое много сделали для разработки супертония, но Вася его вообще не разрабатывал. Если теперь мы хотим подчеркнуть что Вова не просто много сделал для разработки супертония, но еще и принимал в этом непосредственное участие, то как будет правильно?

Comment: Вова проделал большую работу по разработке новых материалов.

Comment: только "работу по разработке" тавтология